# obtener item de la primera lista de un conjunto de listas genericas

Tags: c#

Recibo un listado de "listas genéricas" en C# de esta forma

```
List<WcfService.Entidades.BusquedaEmpleadosOC> datos = cliente.BusquedaEmpleadosOC(ordenCompra, NIT);
```

y todo va bien, recibo la información deseada, el problema ahora es que puedo recibir desde tres listas hasta 25 y quiero obtener el valor del campo #2 de la primera lista, ese y ese en especifico pues por reglas del negocio ahí se guarda un dato importante, podrían indicarme como recuperar el segundo item de la primera lista(debe ser la primera) dentro del listado de listas que recibo

Answer (score 1):

lo dejo por si a alguien le sirve, la respuesta

```
List<WcfService.Entidades.BusquedaEmpleadosOC> datos = cliente.BusquedaEmpleadosOC(ordenCompra, NIT);
            ViewBag.valor = datos[0].tuDato.ToString();
```

Comment: Recuerde **[aceptar su propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**. Saludos.

Comment: Explicar brevemente por qué funcionó también podría ayudar a alguien más

Comment: Si utilizas datos[0] podrias tener error si no existe, recomiendo mejor usar linq y poner .FirstOrDefault() <-- Con esto obtendrias el primer valor y si no existe igual tendrias la entidad pero inicializada.  tambien puedes usar .Single() o .First(), pero si no existe igual tendrias valor null.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a desestimar el primero y obtener el siguiente con LINQ

```
var dato = cliente.BusquedaEmpleadosOC(ordenCompra, NIT).Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```